# How much heat it needs to be applyed to water to boil?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, water, adiabatic

There is a mass of $2kg$of water, it needs to be boiled, then how much energy needs to be supplied?

- Mass of water $2 kg$
- Initial temperature $20 C$
- Final temperature $94 C$
- $C_p$ $4.186\frac{KJ}{kgC}$
- Latent heat $2772.8\frac{KJ}{kgC} $
- Fraction of water evaporated  $10\%$

What I have done is this
$$Q_p=(2 kg)(4.186 kJ/kgC) (94-20)C= 619.528KJ$$
$$Q_l=(2772.8 kJ/kg)(0.10)(2Kg)=554.56KJ$$
$$Q_t=Q_p+Q_l=1174.088KJ$$

Right, its correct, but in the class I was told the "right way" to do it is using the enthalpy at the stages given by the temperature

- $h_3@94C$ and vapour quality=$100\%$=$2666.6KJ/kg$
- $h_2@94C$ and vapour quality=$0\%$=$393.7KJ/kg$
- $h_1@20C$ and vapour quality=$0\%$=$83.94KJ/kg$

but there was no explication about whats the meaning of this. 
How can be applied to  calculate the amount of heat

Comment: How can final temperature be 94 C if it boils?

Comment: @Steeven up in the hills : )    ricci. .....do you know what enthalpy is or have you used it already https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy

Comment: @ CountTo10 Well, but how do you interpret all that types and formulas; whats the meaning of all that article=? , perhaps I need to repeat the course again but  that’s why I’m asking, And thanks for commenting =) I dont see the point of choosing one or other way to do this, since both are correct and for me is more clear to use the cp and latent values to make the numbers.

Comment: There are various ways to do it, but do me a favor and read through this page http://chempaths.chemeddl.org/services/chempaths/?q=book/General%20Chemistry%20Textbook/Solids%2C%20Liquids%20and%20Solutions/1406/enthalpy-fusion-and-enthalpy-vapo   the more methods you have, then the more chances you will be able to solve problems that don't have the variables you expect from earlier problems. So you might get the same question without being given the latent heat, but the calculations involving enthalpy might still solve it for you.

Comment: @CountTo10 Thanks, Whoa!, thats better explained that the wikis around. Very cool site you writed. See you

Comment: You may be interested in the fledgling offshoot site [Physics Problems Q&A](http://physicsproblems.nfshost.com/) which is more geared towards this type of question.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this part of the site you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

OK, very well after reading a bit in the bibliography given, I got this

- My question is more or less a pleonasm, it should be given what is the enthalpy of the system to boil this given maass of water...
- On the other side, sometimes (it depends of what data you have) its a bit more handy to look in tables or to make a simple calculation:

Using enthalpy
 $h_3@94C$ and vapour quality $100\%$=$2666.6KJ/kg$
   $(2666.6\frac{KJ}{kg})(0.20Kg)=533.32KJ$
 - $h_2@94C$ and vapour quality $0\%$=$393.7KJ/kg$
   $(393.7\frac{KJ}{kg})(1.8Kg)=708.66KJ$

- $h_1@20C$ and vapour quality $0\%$=$83.94KJ/kg$
   $(83.94\frac{KJ}{kg})(2Kg)=167.88KJ$

Then $Q_{t}=1409.84KJ$
Thanks!! =)